# multi type list View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

How I can display list View with multi-type for example(item 1: text, item 2: image with Text ...)
using flutter?

Here is the code:
I need to make the ListView show onlyText in item1, imageWithText for item2 and so on, How I can do that?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        ListView.separated(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => onlyText(),
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10),
          itemCount: 100,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}

Widget imageWithText() => Container(
    child: Card(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            'sara ahmad',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Image.network(
            'https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.e3a5da5209f4c39f1899456c94371a6f?rik=mz9sVBWxRJKGgA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fmedia1.santabanta.com%2ffull1%2fAnimals%2fHorses%2fhorses-62a.jpg&ehk=o%2fS9l8DSJtUbl%2bYcrwLMJy6W4MfUby7bTUHRwJu7a%2bU%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
Widget onlyText() => Container(
    child: Card(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            'sara ahmad',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text('Nour'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `itemBuilder` you can check if the item is only text or image with text with a [ternary operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) `?:`, i.e. *`condition ? expr1 : expr2`*, like so:

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) => index == 0 ? onlyText() : imageWithText(),
```

Or, if you have a list of more than 2 items it could be something like this (assuming the items have a property `bool isOnlyText`):

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) => _chats[index].isOnlyText
    ? onlyText()
    : imageWithText(),
```

Below is the result of the 1st snippet above:

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                index == 0 ? onlyText() : imageWithText(),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10),
            itemCount: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, what is the _items[index] ,I want to do a list from these two widgets onlytext and textwithimage, so how I can do a list with different type in the same list ?

Comment: If it's only 2 widgets couldn't it be a `Column` like I've suggested? Or just try the 1st snipped of code above with the ternary operator?

Comment: Please check the updated answer with the screenshot and the code itself.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a screenshot with more than 2 items. I've also added an [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) to align the list to the screen. BTW, the `_items` I'm referring to on the 2nd snippet is the chat list you have. So, each item should tell if it's a `text-only` or `text-with-image` and my approach is to create a property `isOnlyText` to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ///crete an empty widget list
List<Widget> item_list=[];
  ///create a function to add data to list and call this function in the initstate
  add_items_to_list()async{
    item_list.add(Text(('data')));
    item_list.add(Image.asset('name'));
    ///add as much as you want
  }
  
  ///use widget as below
  Widget items()=>ListView(
    children: item_list,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to show static list, you can do like this**

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) => index.isEven
    ? onlyText()
    : imageWithText(),
```

**or you have dynamic data then follow below**

let's assume you have list of `Model class` like this

```
class Model{
 String text,
 String img,
}

var list = <Model>[]; //your data will be here
```

and to check if is there only image, you need condition like below,
so in your `ListView` you can check like this

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) => list[index].img == null
    ? onlyText()
    : imageWithText(),
```

Comment: show me what is in your list, it is depend on your list, so you itemCount will be dynamic like itemCount: list.length

Comment: The items are the two widgets onlyText and imageWithText

Comment: @sara check my edited answer

Comment: No, its dynamic how i can use the two variable text and image

Comment: and how I can add the two widget in the list you created

Comment: where are you getting the list??? from the rest api?? if yes, then add flag in responce of api ,so you can check whether your flag meet your condition or not

you do not need to use those two variable text and image, it was for example

Comment: show me the responce

Comment: it is all depend on backend responce, you can only check condition based on responce and return widget